# Item cannot be added to a read-only or fixed-size list

Tags: winforms, bindingsource

I am using bindingsource . The problem is that when i do `AddNew()` in binding source then it give me the exception `Item cannot be added to a read-only or fixed-size list.` This form is  Dialog. For your review i am adding the code

Main Form Code

```
private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.Validate();
        _earning = (Earning)this.earningBindingSource.Current;
        string EmpNo = Convert.ToString(_earning.Empno == null || _earning.Empno == string.Empty ? "0" : _earning.Empno);
        Incomes.frmIncomeAddList _earnEmployee = new Incomes.frmIncomeAddList();
        _earnEmployee.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

This is the Dialog Form Code

```
public frmIncomeAddList( )
{
    InitializeComponent();  

    FillCurrency();

    FillDropdown();
    FillEarnCode();
    FillEarnCodeDESC();

    this.earningBindingSource.AddNew();

    this.earningBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Enabled = true;

    FillDropdown(); 
}
```

on Dialog Form  `this.earningBindingSource.AddNew();` i am getting exception `Item cannot be added to a read-only or fixed-size list.`

Can you please help me. Thank's in advance

Comment: It's obvious that your BindingSource is bound to fixed size or read-only list. You should change the underlying datasource to make it editable or variable.

Comment: but i am doing `this.earningBindingSource.AddNew();` here i am doing for `.AddNew()`

Comment: I supposed your earningBindingSource is typeof BindingSource and AddNew() will do some adding new row to the underlying data source.

Comment: @KingKing  Then what you suggest ?

Comment: Change your underlying datasource, if you declare it as readonly it can't be changed anyway. I don't know exactly what your datasource is so it's better to update your question to help others see what your datasource is. I usually create my datasource as DataTable. What about yours?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
List<Earning> earnings = ((IEnumerable<Earning>)earningBindingSource.DataSource).ToList();
earnings.Add(new Earning());
earningBindingSource.DataSource = earnings.AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 1):

when parent table has no record, and add new row in child table then show this error.

`Item cannot be added to a read-only or fixed-size list`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `YourBindingSource.AllowNew = true;`

Or from properties window of the BindingSource:

[image]

It worked for me..